# Flutter Notifications: LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_local@359310200' has not been initialized.)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, notifications

```
Future<void> showNotification(
      int id, String title, String body, int seconds) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(Duration(seconds: seconds)),
      const NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails('main_channel', 'Main Channel',
              importance: Importance.max,
              priority: Priority.max,
              icon: '@drawable/ic_flutternotification')),
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
    );

}
```

I got this error `Flutter Notifications: LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_local@359310200' has not been initialized.)` for `tz.local` I can't understand how to solve it, since tz is imported and not defined by me (`import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;`)

[see vscode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTIWm.png)

Answer (score 2):

This is solution for this case:

```
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;

void main() async{
tz.initializeTimeZones();
runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Initialize timezone.

Let me know if this works for you, and also, if works, please set this answer as correct.

Comment: Yes... but with this fix, I now got this other XD https://imgur.com/a/Dirw6XW

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46259

This is similar, you can check this post :) This guy had the same issue.